# ImportError: DLL load failed : - when trying to import psycopg2 library

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

```
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 60, in 
    from _psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its si
de-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log for
more detail.
```

I get this error when trying to import [psycopg2](http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg).. I've searched for days, and found no solutions. 
I've tried installing the Visual C++ 2008 Package, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/e1b628f0f75896f0) you need to install an earlier version since there were problems with the latest build.

> Simply install an earlier version, (2.0.10 works great), even with 
>   PostgreSQL 8.4.x series.

Comment: libpq is not up to date with psycopg2 package. PG6000 is the solution!

Answer (score 19):

On Windows, make sure your path includes the Postgres bin directory. In my machine it's c:\Programs\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin.

Comment: +1 It appears you *do* need the PostgreSQL binaries in your path

Comment: Adding this path entry after installing PostgreSQL on windows from the main site (http://www.postgresql.org/) fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I ran into the exact same problem and solved it this way

Comment: Fixed it for me. One note, however, I did have to close and re-open the command prompt for it to recognize the new PATH.

Answer (score 7):

You can also try installing win-psycopg from [here](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with `virtualenv` and `psycopg2`. I have copied `_psycopg.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` from global python to `\venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2` This worked for me.