# Can I get psycopg2 to work on Windows with a python built with vc9?

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a question similar to [ImportError: DLL load failed : - when trying to import psycopg2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306367/python-importerror-dll-load-failed-when-trying-to-import-psycopg2-library)

I'm trying to run psycopg2 with Python 2.6.5, built with Visual Studio 2008 (vc9).  I get this error:

```
from _psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: DLL load failed: The operating system cannot run %1.
```

libpg.dll, from PostGres 8.4, is in the path.  If I build psycopg2 with a vc6-built python, it will
run fine.  But the problem is that I need it to work with a vc9-built Python.

The page I referenced mentioned using an older version.  When I try building version 2.12.0 (or even 2.10.0),
I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W
3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=\"2.0.10 (dt d
ec ext pq3)\"" -DPG_VERSION_HEX=0x080401 -DPSYCOPG_EXTENSIONS=1 -DPSYCOPG_NEW_BO
OLEAN=1 -DHAVE_PQFREEMEM=1 -DHAVE_PQPROTOCOL3=1 -IC:\Python26\include -IC:\Pytho
n26\PC -I. -Ic:/apps/POSTGR~1/8.4/include -Ic:/apps/POSTGR~1/8.4/include/server
/Tcpsycopg\connection_int.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.6\Release\psycopg\connection_i
nt.obj /Wp64
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be
removed in a future release
connection_int.c
psycopg\connection_int.c(70) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 't
ype'
psycopg\connection_int.c(71) : error C2065: 'notice' : undeclared identifier
psycopg\connection_int.c(71) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of i
ndirection from 'connectionObject_notice *'
psycopg\connection_int.c(73) : error C2065: 'notice' : undeclared identifier
psycopg\connection_int.c(73) : warning C4047: '!=' : 'int' differs in levels of
indirection from 'void *'
```

and on and on....  Looking at the C code, there is no conditional code
wrapping the definition of struct connectionObject_notice, so I don't
see what would trigger this error.

Finally, a poster in the above thread mentioned "PG6000".  What is that?

- Eric

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should install  windows SDK 7.0.

I have vs2005/vs2008/vc2010 and some windows SDK installed in my system, 
and when I install  psycopg2-2.4.2  python package use "python setup.py install",
it prompt me need "mt.exe";
so I add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin"   to path, 
then it will build ok.  but python -c "import psycopg2"  sill fail,  so I add  PostgreSQL client install path:  "...\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin" to system path, then all runs fine.