# Django: psycopg2 import error

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.4

I was having a very weird bug when trying to run migrations in my freshly installed Django app and narrowed it down to the module imports. I found out `django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base` wasn't being imported so I checked my `pyscopg2` installation by going to the Python console and trying `import psycopg2`.

Indeed there was an error with this module:

```
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: DLL failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried uninstalling `psycopg2` with `pip` and installing it again, and several different versions, but I always got the same error.

I installed `win-psycopg`(`psycopg2-2.6.2.win-amd64-py2.7-pg9.5.3-release.exe`) from [here](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/).

I am using Django 1.4.22, Python 2.7.8 64 bits and Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version of Django may help.

Comment: @denvaar That would be impossible, it is not up to me. Anyway, I used this exact same env in a previous machine and I did not have this problem.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306367/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-trying-to-import-psycopg2-library

Comment: "On Windows, make sure your path includes the Postgres bin directory. In my machine it's c:\Programs\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin."

Comment: nvm I found a solution. I am using the newest version of psycopg2 now. For some reason the first time I tried this did not work, but now it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested in my machine with this package `psycopg2-2.6.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl` and it works for me:

```
pip install psycopg2-2.6.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
```

You can get the package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/