# After successful insalliation of psycop2 there was DLL load failed while importing _psycopg error while running any command in my pycharm terminal

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I have installed psycop2 on my virtualenv.

Then after running any command in my pycharm terminal I am getting this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\django_project>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\PycharmProjects\django_pro_postgres\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have configured database details in my **settings.py**:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'overiq',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD' : '123456',
        'HOST' : 'localhost'
    }
}
```

**Error:** django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: DLL load failed while importing _psycopg: The specified module could not be found.

**IDE Used:** PyCharm

**Python version:** 3.8.2

**Django version:** 3.0.5

**OS:** Windows 8.1(32 bit)

I have checked all the settings but I still have the same issue. Can anyone suggest me how to get rid of this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: DLL load failed : - when trying to import psycopg2 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306367/importerror-dll-load-failed-when-trying-to-import-psycopg2-library)

Comment: No this is not the answer that worked out. @MohitC

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions here

1. Use `'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2'`
2. Uninstall the original `psycopg2-binary`, execute the command `pip install psycopg2-binary`

The Python version I used before was 3.6. This problem occurred when I changed to 3.8. I tried to install the latest `psycopg2-binary`, which proved to be effective.